# In App purchases (Removing ads) sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I have fully functional code here for "In App Purchase (removing iAd) that work fine single view application, but I need to implement it in MyScene (SpriteKit) game. here is my ViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>

@property ( nonatomic,strong) NSArray*products;

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSUserDefaults*defaults;

- (IBAction)removeAdvertisment:(id)sender;
@end
```

Here is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "MyScene.h"

#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize  /*idBanner*/ products,defaults;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     //Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];


    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:(id)self];

    defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    BOOL isPro=[defaults boolForKey:@"isPro"];



    if (!isPro) {
        //user code here
        [self fetchProducts];
    }

    else
    {
        //iadBanner.alpha=0.0;

    }

}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [banner setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

-(void)fetchProducts{
    SKProductsRequest*request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:@[@"ProductIDPurchaseID"]]];
    request.delegate = (id)self;
    [request start];
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    products = response.products;
    NSLog(@"The app wass purchased");
}
-(void)request:(SKRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

-(void)buy:(SKProduct*)product{

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addPayment:payment];
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *tx in transactions)   {
        switch (tx.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];
                //_____________________
                //iadBanner.alpha=0.0;
                //______________________

                [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPro"];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];
                NSLog(@"Error:%@",tx.error);
                break;


            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }


}

- (IBAction)removeAdvertisment:(id)sender {

    SKProduct *prod = [products objectAtIndex:0];
    [self buy:prod];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


@end
```

When you press UIButton it make whole code to work pup up message appears and player can remove adds by buying "remove ads"

This method makes hole code work

- (IBAction)removeAdvertisment:(id)sender {

  SKProduct *prod = [products objectAtIndex:0];
  [self buy:prod]; 
  }

but I nee it to be called from MyScene class subclass of SKScene

So the question is how do I call removeAdvertisement(button above) method from MyScene class?

Answer (score 0):

create a singleton  of ViewController in ur SKScene such as

//.h file

```
@property  UIViewController *gameViewController;
```

//.h file

insilde .m file of your SKScene

```
 gameViewController= (UIViewController*)self.view.window.rootViewController;
```

now you can access any public function of your UIViewController by

```
[gameViewController removeAdvertisement(@"value")];
```

Comment: So I created a singleton of ViewController in my MyScene.h file, then I created a new method in MyScene.m file like so -(void)inAccess{
    
    _gameViewController= (UIViewController*)self.view.window.rootViewController;
    
[_gameViewController removeAdvertisement(@"value")];
}  and I want to put this "inAccess" method in "TouhchesBegins" but this line of code is not working, it is not recognised by compiler and giving me stupid mistake like "expected ']' " and buy the way what does "(@"value")" means in this line [gameViewController removeAdvertisement(@"value")];?What should I put there?

Comment: sorry its my mistake  [gameViewController removeAdvertisement]; where removeAdvertisement is a public function which  you declared in  view controller

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will try your suggestions latter, and I upvoted you reply anyway! Hope this works but thanks for attempt to help anyway. If it work I will mark you answer as "Answered" thanks again.